# Referencing cell on other tab in formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to reference the same (row,column) on the different tab in the same google spreadsheet document?

So, I want to do something like this:
=SOME_FORMULA('First tab'!(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))). This doesn't work.

If the formula isn't apsolutly referenced, entries of Google Forms questionnaire change the reference and mess up the formula. (the formula that looked at row number 5 after insert looks at row number 6) I can't use apsolute referencing ($A$1) because I have to enter it manually.

Can I change the reference on multiple cells? (for one I can use cmd + f4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that annoying reference problem too. If I understand correctly you are trying to get the information on some cells, but every time someone sends information to the spreadsheet by filling up a Form, that reference moves down a row.

The best solution I came up with was to create a new SpreadSheet and import all the information with this:

```
=importrange("spreadsheet-key","Form Responses!A1:B2107")
```

That function updates the info in realtime, so you can do all the processing on the new spreadsheet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not quite understand what you need. Need to reference a cell in another sheet given coordinates on the current cell where it is located?

If so, the following formula can be useful:

```
=INDIRECT("First tab!"&ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))
```

Comment: Yes Indirect is what you want but be aware that it has performance penalties as the formula will reevaluate when any cell anywhere changes.